# Element won't center

Tags: css

I created a carousel with the following html code

```
<div id='projCarousel'>
   <div class='active'>
       <a href='http://www.#.com' target='_blank'>#</a>
       <img id='projImg' src='img/#.png' class='active' />
   </div>
   <div>
       <a href='http://www.#.com' target='_blank'>#</a>
       <img id='projImg' src='img/#.png' />
   </div>
</div>
```

I noticed that the #projCarousel div a were not centering. I did some searching and found that the proper way to center a element would be with the css

```
#projCarousel div a {
   margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto;
}
```

I've tried multiple things and narrowed down that the problem is either with me using the position:relative or display:inline. I am not sure what the exact problem is with using the two together like this. Does anyone have any advice on why its not working. This is the css I am currently using for the carousel.

```
#projCarousel {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width:100%;
}

#projImg {
 width:100%;
 height: auto;
 margin-top: -24px;
}

#projCarousel div {
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
 position:absolute;
 min-width:100%;
 min-height: 100%
}

#projCarousel div a {
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  left: 44.5%;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 10px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .6);
  font-size: 20px;    
  display: inline;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
 width: 200px;
}
```

On a side note, I thought it might be easier to just remove the  tags altogether and just use

```
  background-image:url(img/#.png);
```

but that does not want to work either. Sorry about all the text.

Comment: can you describe more what you're trying to achieve with this carousel ?

Comment: Its just a image carousel for projects i've worked on. It auto cycles between the two divs adding a z-index to whichever one is active at the time.

Comment: So all `#projCarousel div` are supposed to overlay each other?

Comment: yes they are supposed to stack one on the other and then cycle

Answer (score 0):

You can pack it with another div outside to make projCarousel center

```
   <div style='width:100%; margin:0 auto'>

   <div id='projCarousel'>
      <div class='active'>
        <a href='http://www.#.com' target='_blank'>#</a>
        <img id='projImg' src='img/#.png' class='active'/>
      </div>

      <div>
       <a href='http://www.#.com' target='_blank'>#</a>
       <img id='projImg' src='img/#.png' />
      </div>
   </div>

   </div>
```

Comment: would that center the anchor tags?

Comment: it will center everything which be cover, which anchor you mean?

Comment: the anchors inside of the nested divs. they are not centering

Answer (score 0):

I would propose the following solution (jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9KE8r/):

HTML

```
<div id="projCarousel">
   <div style="background-image: url(http://placehold.it/350x150);">
       <a>#</a>
   </div>
   <div style="background-image: url(http://placehold.it/200x150);">
       <a>#</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#projCarousel{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px blue;
}
#projCarousel div{
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}
#projCarousel div:first-child{
    position: relative;
}
#projCarousel div a{
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Some details:

- `background-image` is defined inline (ie. in the HTML) so that it can easily be different for each div.
- I don't really recommend the use of `min-height:100%`. Here I went with a fixed `px` height. But with this solution, your `#projCarousel` will take the height of whatever you put in it anyway.
- The use of `display:table;` on the parent and `display:table-cell;` on the child allows for cool vertical centering. If you don't need that, you can just replace the all the `div` inside `#projCarousel` by `a` and discard the innermost `a` in each.